# Angular getting error core.js:35929 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: angular

I have an angular project running on my PC without any errors. When I try to open the project on another PC I get this error when running the cliend side (backend runs without problems):

```
core.js:35929 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:35929)
    at core.js:35947
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:35943)
    at core.js:35947
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:35943)
    at new NgModuleFactory$1 (core.js:36105)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (core.js:41895)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:42260)
```

Please help me understand what i'm missing in the new computer,I believe it might be even a code line i need to run in the console like npm..

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access 'id' property of something which is undefined(not initialized) in an array. If your project is not big enough , you can search for ".id" in *.ts files and if result set is small you can figure out where the problem is. Also if you can provide the project source , it will be easier to help you. -- Thanks

Comment: But how come that in my computer I don't get this error? the project is pretty much big so it isn't that easy to search for this specific id

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are getting this error because of version mismatch for some module

I got the same error for `lodash` version mismatch

To find the culprit you can use following approach and change its version

[image]

In sources tab of your chrome devtools

1. click on this pause icon on extreme right
2. Check the `pause on exception` checkbox

Now it will pause before breaking and you can know which module's version needs to be changed